# Upgrade Sonar (tomcat+sonar)

Tags: tomcat6, sonarqube

I have installed apache-tomcat with sonar 2.9. I need to upgrade the sonar to the newest version. What should I do to make this upgrade through the tool itself?

Environment :

- linux - debian wheezy
- jdk 1.6
- sonar 2.9 upgrade to 3.5
- apache-tomcat-6.0.36

Comment: Strange you didn't inform about database being used. You can directly upgrade with Sonar 5.4 LTS. Database upgrade is taken care by ruby scripts, make sure you backup the db.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all required information on the following upgrade guide documentation:

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Upgrade+Guide

As you are upgrading from a quite old version of Sonar, here are some advises:

- You don't need to updgrade version by version, you can upgade directly from 2.9 to 3.5.1
- However, please read all the release upgrade notes from 2.9 to 3.5.1 in order to not miss some important changes
- And obviously: **please backup your database before starting the migration**, in case some trouble would happen during the process

If you follow this, everything should be fine!

Comment: You should come on the Sonar user mailing list to discuss this, it will be difficult on Stackoverflow comments to display stacktrace and so on.

Answer (score 0):

INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor sonar.xml
16:44:00,697 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
16:44:00,698 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
16:44:00,698 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.xml]
16:44:00,699 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Setting up default configuration.
16:44:00,892 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
16:44:00,894 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
16:44:00,894 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [SONAR_WAR]
16:44:00,928 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.boolex.JaninoEventEvaluator] for [evaluator] property
16:44:00,952 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.boolex.JaninoEventEvaluator@4c538974 - Adding [return] prefix and a semicolon suffix. Expression becomes [return message.startsWith("files: File not found: /maven");]
16:44:00,952 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.boolex.JaninoEventEvaluator@4c538974 - See also http://logback.qos.ch/codes.html#block
16:44:01,060 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[SONAR_WAR] - This appender no longer admits a layout as a sub-component, set an encoder instead.
16:44:01,060 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[SONAR_WAR] - To ensure compatibility, wrapping your layout in LayoutWrappingEncoder.
16:44:01,060 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[SONAR_WAR] - See also http://logback.qos.ch/codes.html#layoutInsteadOfEncoder for details

Comment: Add this to your question and explain